# How setState to nested array in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If I have a state:

```
this.state = {
    data: [
      {
         match: false,
         value: "Some"
      }
    ],
};
```

In handler function I can add new value like that? It's correct?

```
  inputKeydown = (e) => {
    const val = e.target.value;
    if (e.key === 'Enter' && val) {
      this.setState({ data: [...this.state.data, {match: false, value:val}]});
    } 
  }
```

With this way I will get my state like that?

```
this.state = {
   data: [
     {
        match: false,
        value: "Some"
     },
     {
        match: false,
        value: "input value"
     },
   ],
};
```

Comment: What you want exactly? Want to change existing values or add new values?

Comment: i think you want to get array of objects?

Comment: i want to add new values yes.

Comment: Yes. you are doing it correctly.

Comment: Thanks :) It's worked but i just wanted to be sure it's correct way or not

Answer (score 0):

Another way of adding values to existing state array is,

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
    ...prevState,
    data: prevState.data.concat({match: false, value:val})
  }),()=>console.log(this.state.data)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `push` method...

```
{
  let dataArray = this.state.data;
  dataArray.push({match: false,value: e.target.value});
  this.setState ({
    data:data array
  });
}
```